# how to solve winerror 5 in python?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

my code is this but for some reason its not working?

```
# opening an image from the source path
img = Image.open('text1.png')

# describes image format in the output
print(img)
# path where the tesseract module is installed
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = (
    r'C:\Users\Sayan Dutta Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract')

# converts the image to result and saves it into result variable
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

the error i am getting is `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this as well, solution is usually to be sure to run the program as an administrator (right click, run as administrator.)

Comment: sorry im new to coding could you specify e\which program to run as administrator?

Comment: you can run cmd as administrator and run python file